# Plotting ellipses based on subset of data

Tags: r, plot, statistics, data-science

I'm comparing isotope data between two species of fish in R. Specifically, i want to look at niche size (roughly inferred by size of ellipse around the points). I've attached a plot to show the sort of plot I'm making (three fish on plot but one is being ignored statistically) [Isotope plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K39x5.png)

The problem is, my sample sizes are 68 for species 1 (blue marlin), and 15 for species 2 (striped marlin), and i need to examine the effect different sample sizes will have on the size of the 95% confidence ellipse.

How this issue is typically tackled is to essentially plot the 15 samples i have for species 2 against a subset of 15 samples from species 1. If the line of the ellipse is slightly transparent, and I plot it several 100 times, the darker areas will reveal the 'true niche'.

I have managed to plot my points, but have no idea how to plot 100s of ellipses based on random subsets of my data?

My data is set out in the following columns: 'fish.id' - which has blue marlin (BM) and striped marlin (SM); '15N' - which has my nitrogen values; and '13C' - which has my carbon values.

```
`fish.id`  `15N` `13C`
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 BkM6F    14    15
 2 BkM7F    10    16
 3 BkM8F    11    16
 4 BkM9F    11    18
 5 BM12F    13    17
 6 BM14F    13    20
 7 BM17F    11    17
 8 BM18F    15    19
 9 BM19F    13    17
10 BM22F    13    16
# … with 79 more rows
```

This is what I have so far:

```r
#plot with all points
plot(Isotope$`13C`,Isotope$`15N`,type='n', 
     main = 'Marlin 13C vs 15N', xlab = '13C', ylab = '15N')
points(Isotope$`13C`[substr(Isotope$fish.id,1,2)=='Bk'], 
       Isotope$`15N`[substr(Isotope$fish.id,1,2)=='Bk'], pch=15, col = 'black')
points(Isotope$`13C`[substr(Isotope$fish.id,1,2)=='BM'], 
       Isotope$`15N`[substr(Isotope$fish.id,1,2)=='BM'], pch=16, col = 'dodgerblue3')
points(Isotope$`13C`[substr(Isotope$fish.id,1,2)=='SM'], 
       Isotope$`15N`[substr(Isotope$fish.id,1,2)=='SM'], pch=17, col = 'cadetblue3')

#attempt at subsetting data
plot( )

for(i in 1:1000) {

  sampl1 <- sample(1:15,size=15,replace=TRUE)
  sampl2 <- sample(1:69,size=15,replace=TRUE)

  temp.data1 <- data1[sampl1,]
  temp.data2 <- data2[sampl2,]

}
```

Cheers for the help!

Comment: Without sample data we cannot demonstrate the solution for you, but you need the `ellipse()` function in either the `car` or `ellipse` package and you need to add transparency to your color with the `alpha=` argument in the `rgb()` function.

Comment: Hey dcarlson, cheers for the help! I'll add some sample data to the post. I had been using the addEllipse function from SIBER, but might try the ones you've suggested.

Comment: Use `dput(as.data.frame(Isotope))` and paste 15 rows for each species, or the whole thing. Your coding will be simpler if you create a `species` column in your data with just the species labels. That alone would reduce your plot statement to a couple of lines. Then use `C13` and `N14` as your isotope variable names. That would save you lots of typing since you would not need to surround the names with `name`. The `SIBER` package comes with multiple [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SIBER/index.html)  illustrating its use that may allow you to do things more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started that takes my earlier comments into account. First, reproducible data so we are talking about the same thing:

```
dat <- structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Bk", "BM"), class = "factor"), 
    N15 = c(13.06, 11.57, 13.28, 13.45, 11.91, 12.01, 14.04, 
    11.97, 13.46, 11.27, 13.37, 14.23, 11.32, 11.58, 12.1, 12.42, 
    12.63, 11.52, 13.72, 12.3, 14.49, 14.01, 13.24, 15.03, 12.93, 
    12.71, 13.1, 12.26, 14.74, 14.18), C13 = c(17.51, 15.37, 
    15.4, 15.73, 16.84, 15.79, 16.78, 15.85, 18.32, 16.61, 17.07, 
    18.05, 14.08, 15.9, 15.65, 18.27, 18.95, 18.46, 17.58, 18.24, 
    16.28, 17.54, 16.65, 15.51, 18, 18.09, 17.42, 18.68, 18.38, 
    16.62)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
str(dat)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ species: Factor w/ 2 levels "Bk","BM": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ N15    : num  13.1 11.6 13.3 13.4 11.9 ...
 $ C13    : num  17.5 15.4 15.4 15.7 16.8 ...
```

Making `species` a factor simplifies using it to specify colors, symbols:

```
idx <- as.numeric(dat$species)
sym <- 15:16
cls <- c("dodgerblue3", "cadetblue3")
col1 <- c(col2rgb(cls[1]))
col1 <- rgb(col1[1], col1[2], col1[3], 64, maxColorValue=255) # 25% transparency
col2 <- c(col2rgb(cls[2]))
col2 <- rgb(col2[1], col2[2], col2[3], 64, maxColorValue=255)
alpha.col <- c(col1, col2)
```

This creates symbols for each group, colors for each group, and transparent colors:

```
library(car)
plot(N15~C13, dat, xlim=c(12, 21), ylim=c(10, 17), xlab="13C", ylab="15N", pch=sym[idx], col=cls[idx])
dataEllipse(dat$C13, dat$N15, groups=dat$species, levels=.95, center.cex=1.25, add=TRUE, plot.points=FALSE,
     col=alpha.col)
```

Which creates the following plot:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks so much! In hindsight, the way I had set out my plot was really messy, ah well, lesson learnt :)